# How to step into Linq.FindAll query to determine cause of failure using a breakpoint

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, findall

I want to use the `FindAll` method in C# in like this:

```
List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
cards.AddRange(testCaseCards);
Console.WriteLine(cards.Count);
List<List<Card>> cardsSuits = new List<List<Card>>();
List<Card> tempList = new List<Card>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cards[i].Suit);
    tempList = cards.FindAll(card => card.Suit == (Suit)i);
    cardsSuits.Add(tempList);
}
```

When I initialize my code with `testCaseCards` containing 9 cards, everything works just fine up until the `FindAll` query. The value of `cards.Count` is 9 and `cards[i].Suit` returns the respective suits.

But when `FindAll` executes it throws an exception that "`card` was null" and I'm looking for a way to **step into** the `FindAll` as it goes through the cards and **set a breakpoint** to examine values and determine the exact cause of failure. I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) which mentions `Linq` in passing but doesn't provide any real guidance about debugging a null exception *while* the `Linq` query is running.

Also, if you notice any other problems in my code please point them out.

Comment: How is `Suit` defined? What is `testCaseCards`? Can you show a more [complete example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sorry for not giving more information. Suit is an enumeration of traditional card suits (Clubs, Diamonds etc.) and testCaseCards is just an array of Cards (a class containing the Suits enumeration). I thought that this was not so important as the only think not working is the exception telling me that card is null which I don't understand because the line of code above (Console.WriteLine(cards[i].Suit);) works just fine.

Comment: You're getting this error because `testCaseCards` contains a null value. There's no way for us to know why it contains a null value without seeing the code that initializes/populates it.

Comment: To confirm 'testCaseCards' contains null value you could try `tempList = cards.FindAll(card => card?.Suit == (Suit)i) ` which should not throw any errors

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with the card? I also found why there was a null value in the first place. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug the `FindAll` (or any `Linq`) is by creating a `Predicate` method. For example:

```
private static bool isSuit(Card card, Suit suit)
{
    if (card == null)
    {
        // Set a break point here. When the null card comes in
        // (as it surely will) you can answer 'why' for yourself.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "Expecting a non-null card");
        return false; // But at least it won't crash now.
    }
    else
    {
        return card.Suit == suit;
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to step into this method by changing your `FindAll` statement to call the predicate instead:

```
tempList = cards.FindAll(card => isSuit(card, suit));
```

In addition there is another potential problem. You have a loop where `i` could mean *anything*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
```

In fact the first two statements in the loop interpret it in very different ways. The first statement in the loop seems to think that `i` is the index in the `cards` collection. You say `cards` holds 9 cards. Why stop the loop after 4 then?

```
Console.WriteLine(cards[i].Suit);
```

On the other hand, the second line tries to cast `i` to `Suit` (which has only four values). if `i` *does* go past 4, this won't be good. I would strongly encourage you to *change your loop* to something like this where we know for sure which collection is being iterated:

```
foreach (Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
{
    Console.Write(suit.ToString());
    tempList = cards.FindAll(card => isSuit(card, suit));
    cardsSuits.Add(tempList);
    Console.WriteLine($" has {tempList.Count} cards.");
}
```

The test case I ran gets this:

[image: 9 Clubs has 1 cards. Diamonds has 2 cards. Hearts has 3 cards. Spades has 3 cards.]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! The Console.WriteLine(cards[i].Suit); was only a crude attempt at debugging but the tip with Enum.GetValues is very nice indeed! :)

Comment: Glad to assist! I submitted a new edit because your post raises a distinct and useful question about how to nail down root cause of a null (or any other) exception that's thrown _while_ a `Linq` query is executing and my hope is to see it reopened. IMO it's an oversimplification to say this is a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).